Azure Load Balncers and Application Gateway in a Disaster recovery architecture on a different reg
I need to create a DR solution for my application running in production
My architecture consists of multiple VMS and multiple load balancers and Application Gateways
I have decided to go with Azure Site Recovery for my VMs, I am confused how to go with my load balancers, because are there any replication for the load balancers possible
also need to put the backend pools a nd frontend if I am creating an LB, which wont be created in the other region unless there is actually a DR possibility
Have seen docs of Traffic Manager and everything, but I have load balancers at different stages ( have one LB which sends traffic to a VM which sends to another LB which finally sends the production VM)

To develop a disaster recovery (DR) solution for your Azure architecture, employ Azure Site Recovery for VM replication and manually set up corresponding Load Balancers and Application Gateways in your DR region. Use Azure Traffic Manager for DNS management and traffic rerouting according to regional health. Automate the updating of backend pools and routinely test the failover procedure to ensure reliability and swift recovery in the event of disasters. @TaanuAbbas
